# How to run dmypy in pre-commit

Tags: python, mypy

To speed up mypy in huge project I want to replace mypy with dmypy to use caching.

But I get a lot of errors like "[Errno 61] Connection refused" and "Daemon crashed!".

Answer (score 1):

You have to run dmypy sequantially, because the daemon can handle only one request at a time

So you have to add `require_serial` to your pre-commit config, something like that:

```
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: mypy
        name: mypy
        entry: dmypy
        files: \.py$
        language: python
        require_serial: true
        args: ["run", "--", "--strict", "--implicit-reexport", "--warn-unused-ignores", "--cache-fine-grained"]
```

And do not forget `--cache-fine-grained`

Comment: Does this actually still result in a performance gain over running mypy from the command line ?

Comment: Honestly I just upgraded my laptop and now use plain mypy CLI 8-)